# How to have env specific log4j2 config for spring boot2 application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Currently spring boot seems to support only classpath based logging configuration.

It also ignores any configuration passed as vm argument as follows.

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/xyz/log4j2-prod.xml
```

How can we have different log4j2 configuration based on different environment, considering classpath for all environment remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about set the properties: `logging.config=classpath:log4j2-dev-spring.xml` in each **application-{profile}.properties** that you have. Can use like this too: `logging.config=${ENV_VAR}`

Comment: Though answer by @Varesh is also correct .This one is even more generic, where if needed, classpath prefix can be replaced directly by filepath. I wasn't aware about logging.config prop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following param

```
-Dlogging.config='/path/to/log4j2.xml'
```